# MySQL Math Functions - Get Percentage Done - (Add 2 Columns, divide and multiply)

Tags: mysql, math

Im trying to calculate a percentage in a MySQL query.

I have a table:

```
Table: Domains
id   url_count   checked   tablekey_id
1    2           1         10
2    1           2         10
3    1           1         15
4    2           1         22
5    2           2         10
```

So the math is :

```
((SUM of the `url_count` column where `checked` >= 2 and `tablekey_id` = 10) / (SUM of the `url_count` column where `tablekey_id` = 10)) *100)
```

The numbers for the above equation would look like:
    (3 / 5) * 100 = 60%

Thanks a bunch guys! I didn't realize you could put an if statement inside of the SUM. I worded my original question terribly so I wanted to post my solution in case someone is having the same issue.

```
SELECT (
(SUM(IF(`checked` >= 1, `url_count`, 0)) / SUM(`url_count`))*100
) AS percent
FROM `google_sort_backlink_domains`
WHERE `tablekey_id` = 10
```

Comment: Your “question” does not ask any question. It should contain an interrogative sentence terminated with a “?”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use IF() function, e.g. -

```
SELECT (
    SUM(IF(checked >= 2, url_count, 0)) / COUNT(IF(checked <= 2, 0, NULL))
  ) * 100
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

@Devart's answer is 100% correct, but you can also do this using `CASE` syntax as I've shown below.

```
SELECT (
    SUM(CASE WHEN checked >= 2 THEN url_count ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(CASE WHEN checked <= 2 THEN 0 END)
  ) * 100
FROM table
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with a different solution but I will keep the Case statements in mind next time Im working on a query.